# Visual Studio Color Format Redundant Code

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio installed in one PC in which text editor is format redundant code by color (as shown in the screen shot).

I want to activate this in visual studio copy installed on another PC.

[image: Visual Studio Screen Shot]

Comment: You have three things highlighted in the picture. It's not clear which one exactly you mean and also not clear what you mean by redundant code. Please clarify. Also, what VS version are you using? Please include that as well because it could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Visual Studio feature, it is one of ReSharper Code Inspection features, hence you'll need to install ReSharper on the computer where you'd like to see this code coloring...

Comment: I am using  Visual studio 2015 (as i mentioned in my comment) and i am sure it has the feature.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/18/how-to-use-reference-highlighting/

Comment: @Soundararajan What feature? It's not clear _(at least to me)_ from the post what exactly the OP is referring to! Is it the highlight on `CategoryDetails`? Is it the number of references? What does that have to do with "redundant code"? Is he referring to an empty space colored yellow in the second line? IDK! I downvoted the question for the lack of clarity _and_ responsiveness.

Comment: @Soundararajan The link you provided is for reference highlighting feature, not code inspection feature as described in the question. For VS this.ID is something perfectly normal and there is nothing in Visual Studio that would point that out as something unnecessary...

Comment: My inference of the question of redundant code means, "CategoryDetails", in this case it's reference highlighting. But i agree, that we will have to wait for the author of the post to confirm that.

Answer (score -2):

This is a visual studio (mine is 2015) feature and should be enabled. By default it should be enabled, but am not sure what version of visual studio you are using. You can enable it by going to Visual Studio -> Tools menu -> Options

[image]